# How I can add custom block to layout using php in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, event-observer, custom-block

I have created a custom block, as I want to add this layout to my current layout.

Following is my block:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Block" name="ucTntlZsQVjVytW4xjtfdypv9LTzRsFP" template="Vendor_ModuleName::myBlock.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
```

I want to add this block to my current block for that I created following event:

> core_layout_render_element

Now how can I add this block to layout using PHP

Need Help!!

Comment: May I know the purpose why you created an event for adding a custom block? It can be added simply.

Comment: i want to add a slider on any page at any location according to his need..

Comment: For That purpose why you don't try widget?

Comment: Then as you described xml sample code, is perfect one. You just need to use same <block> tag in the required xml layout files.

Comment: @RutveeSojitra i have already done this by widget .. but my client want this functionality  in admin form

Comment: @DharaBhatti but if i want to allow user to add on product page or catagory page or home page according to his need

Comment: For that you have to provide options (category page, product page, home page) in admin configuration. Then according to that config settings, you can show specific block in accordingly xml file with the use of "ifconfig" attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this event:
**layout_load_before**

```
<event name="layout_load_before">
    <observer name="bannerlayoutloadbefore" instance="Vendor\ModuleName\Observer\Bannerlayoutloadbefore" shared="false" />
</event>
```

And use the below php code to render the layout:

```
$layout = '<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
        <block class="Vendor\ModuleName\Block\Frontend\Block" name="ucTntlZsQVjVytW4xjtfdypv9LTzRsFP" template="Vendor_ModuleName::myBlock.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>';
$observer->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addUpdate($layout);
```

Use the above code in your observer's execute function.

Comment: It seems bad practice to write layout XML inside PHP.

Comment: @BenCrook any other way to do this??

Comment: Yes but I have checked Amasty's extension who uses the same code in their Part Finder extension to load dynamic layout and I think they are reputed Magento extension provider. I am just trying answere just according to the question Waqar asked.

Comment: @SukumarGorai i m trying this .. Thank for Your answer

Comment: @SukumarGorai thank you this worked for me i have been strucked in this issue from last 15 days thank you so much

Comment: @WaqarAli You Welcome. Happy Coding!